# Prove the linear independence of $\{v_1,v_2+v_2 \}\,$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Prove that if $\{v_1,v_2\}$ are linearly independent (LI), then also $\{v_1,v_1+v_2\}$ are linearly independent.
> Is the converse true?

I have proved the first part, but now i am stuck on whether the converse is true.

that is, if the $ \{ v_1,v_1+v_2 \} $ are LI, so are $\{v_1,v_2\}$.
How can i prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second part consider that if $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent then so are $v_1$ and $-v_2$

Comment: I note that this is *essentially* the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4331096/9754

Answer (score 3):

The reverse can be proved with the usual definition of linear independence.

Let $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}$ be such that $c_1 v_1+c_2v_2=0$. Then
$$0=c_1v_1+c_2v_2=c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_2v_1-c_2v_1=(c_1-c_2)v_1+c_2(v_1+v_2)$$

Because $v_1,v_1+v_2$ are linearly independent, we must conclude $c_1-c_2=c_2=0$, which leads to $c_1=c_2=0$ and proves $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: How can i write the form : if ihave (v1,v1+v2,v1+v2+v3) linearly independent?

Comment: You would use the same argument I wrote. Please go through my proof and work through it until you understand it. You will be sure you understand it once you can do the 3D case, or any n-D case.

Comment: Sorry, but i am still not understanding it. Can you please explain the 3 -D form for me.Thank you.

Comment: Start from $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=0$. Now add and subtract terms (like I added and subtracted $c_2v_1$ in the proof above) and combine them until you get three terms: $v_1, v_1+v_2, v_1+v_2+v_3$, each term multiplied by a scalar. Linear independence of $(v_1,v_1+v_2,v_1+v_2+v_3)$ will dictate that all scalars will need to be zero. This will lead to $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.

Comment: Is this right c1v1-c2v1-c3v1+c1v1+c2v2-c3v3+c1v1+c2v2+c3v3 ?

Comment: Can i have a response please?

Comment: @yaman for proving in higher dimensions , you might want to consider an approach with system of linear equation rather than just writing it out like that . Represent the relations as a system of equations in $c_{1},c_{2},....c_{n}$ and then show that the determinant is non-zero which would prove linear independence.

Answer (score 1):

$\{v_1 ,v_1 +v_2 \}$ L.I $\implies \{v_1,v_2 \}$ L.I

Proof : Assume the contrary that $\{v_1,v_2 \}$  L.D

Then, $v_2 =\lambda v_1$ for some scalar $\lambda$

Then $v_1+ v_2 = (1+\lambda ) v_1$

And this implies $\{v_1 ,v_1 +v_2 \}$ is linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers by @Suzane And @S.G are  great.

This is a bit different and a more general way to prove this for $n$ vectors.

Take the linearly independent set $\mathcal{B}=\{v_{1},v_{1}+v_{2},v_{1}+v_{2}+v_{3},...,v_{1}+v_{2}+..+v_{n}\}$

But denote it by $\mathcal{B}=\{w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{n}\}$.

Then $v_{1}=w_{1}$,

$v_{2}=w_{2}-w_{1},$

$\vdots$

$v_{k}=w_{k}-w_{k-1}\,,2\leq k\leq n$

So if we were to write the matrix of this transformation wrt to basis $w_{1},w_{2},...,w_{n}$ it would be:-

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0&\cdots &0\\
0& 1 &-1&\cdots &0\\
0&0&1&-1\cdots &0\\
\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&&-1\\
0&0&\cdots&&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

It is a simple induction to show that the determinant of the matrix is $1$. Hence $\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{n}\}$ are linearly independent as the invertible map takes basis to basis.

Answer (score 0):

$\because\{v_1,v_1+v_2\}$ are LI;

$\therefore \alpha.v_1+\beta. (v_1+v_2)=0$ holds if $\alpha=\beta=0$

$ \implies (\alpha+\beta)v_1+\beta.v_2=0$ holds if $\alpha=\beta=0$

or, $c_1.v_1+c_2.v_2=0$ holds if $\alpha=\beta=0$ where $c_1=\alpha+\beta, c_2=\beta$

Equivalently, $c_1.v_1+c_2.v_2=0$ holds if $c_1=c_2=0$