# Prove the linearly independence

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that if {v1,v2,v3} are linearly independent (LI), then also {v1,v1+v2,v1+v2+v3} are linearly independent.
Is the reverse true?

I have proved the first part, but now i am stuck on whether the reverse is true.

so if the {v1,v1+v2,v1+v2+v3} are LI, are also {v1,v2,v3} LI? How can i prove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: matrix \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} is invertible

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start: let's call the vectors $w_1:=v_1,~w_2:=v_1+v_2,~w_3:=v_1+v_2+v_3$. Put the vectors $w_1,w_2,w_3$ as the rows of a $3\times n$ matrix $A$ (I'm assuming the vectors are in $\mathbb R^n$ or $\mathbb C^n$, something with $n$-components).

If we're assuming that $w_1,w_2,w_3$ are linearly independent, then the rank of $A$ is $3$ (note that $n\geq 3$ necessarily; why?). Is there some things we can do to $A$ to figure out if $v_1,v_2,v_3$ are linearly independent?